# Apache Zeppelin: passing parameters between different interpreters

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, greenplum

Here's a problem.

I'm building a dashboard in Apache Zeppelin using org.postgresql.Driver to connect to Greenplum database. Usually I use something like:

```
where country_title like '${country=UK,UK|USA|Canada|%}'
```

to pass parameters into my query. But I have a long list of other parameters (like "towns") which I also need to pass to my query. And they are different for different *country_title* values. I can use something like:

```
select towns from towns_by_country where country_title like '${country=UK,UK|USA|Canada|%}'
```

to get a list of towns. How can I use it as a parameter in drop-down menu (WITH '%', of course).

I can use *z.angularBind* or *z.put* & *z.get* , of course. But they work in *%spark* interpreters, not in custom interpreters.

I would be very grateful for an answer or any other constructive feedback.

Comment: Via which interpreter do you want to display this dropdown list ? and what kind of action do you want to run when selection of the dropdown list is changed ?

Comment: I'd like to use interpreter with "org.postgresql.Driver" as a main way of working with DB. So, dropdown list should (if possible) displayed in it. How can I form "'${country=UK,UK|USA|Canada|%}'" lines to use in it?

Comment: hmm, I see, you want to pass one paragraph's result to another paragraph as the values of the dropdown list, right ? I am afraid zeppelin can not do it right now, feel free to create ticket for that

Comment: Thank you! Will try to do it.

Comment: Created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3716